# Powershell: Unable to use the -Recursive switch for AD group membership

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have (what I think is) an odd problem.

I have two domain admin accounts and one domain controller (for the purpose of this question). Here is the scenario:

1. Admin1 RDPs to dc01 and runs the Powershell command (see command below), and it succeeds
2. Admin2 RDPs to dc01 and runs the Powershell command (see command below), and it fails (see error below).

In both cases, we are entering the credentials of admin1 when prompted by Get-Credential

Command: 
    Get-ADGroupMember administrators -Credential (Get-Credential) -Server dc01 -Recursive

Error:
    Get-ADGroupMember : There is no such object on the server

If I remove the -Recursive parameter, then the command works for both admins (again, using the credentials of admin1). If I open ADUC as admin1, then look at the members of Administrators, I can see all members, opening sub-groups without issue.

What in the world is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Are both admins running elevated?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Can you manually recurse with those creds? Do you get the same error if you run powershell as Admin1? Maybe create a job that runs as Admin1 that performs the request in a session running those credentials?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, neither is elevated.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, I can manually recurse in that I can open Administrators and all of the sub groups in ADUC. Admin1 is actually a service account. There is a schedule job that runs the command to generate a report, which is failing. Admin2 is my user account.

Comment: How is the scheduled job setup? That could be the problem.

Comment: The script reads an encrypted credential file, and uses that to run the command as described above (using $cred instead of (Get-Credential)).

Comment: How is the job triggered? Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Yup. Run as a user with rights to read the encrypted credential file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like it was a permissions issue. I added the service account to Enterprise Admins and the failure stopped. I have no idea which object is causing the failure.